# Best way to use a static array

Tags: android, arrays

In my little app, I have a long list of data. Before, I used an editor to let the user enter the data - but now I would like to put the data static in program code/string list value Folder.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what is the data type of array ???

Comment: We cannot help without code examples that show what you mean.

Comment: a list of 15 maybe Data (1000,15) i 'dont have code so far - just thinking first how to do it the best way

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the values inside array you can crate string array inside strings.xml file which is present under values.

example:
    XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="sports_array">
        <item>Football</item>
        <item>Cricket</item>
        <item>Hockey</item>
        <item>Tennis</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves a string array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] sportlist = res.getStringArray(R.array.sports_array);
```

so now your sportlist will contain all the items specified in sports_array which is declared inside strings.xml

for more information pls see 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html